# How to pass two arrays to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort the wordList array and wordCount array. They are parralel arrays and I want to sort it according to the count of each word. I cannot use its built-in sort function so I need to write one. But I don't know why my codes failed:

```
wordList = ["apple", "have", "pear", "here"];
wordCount = [3, 1, 3, 5];
sortWords(wordList, wordCount);
function sortWords(arr1, arr2) {
 .....
}
```

Does my code successfully pass these two arrays to the function?

Comment: "Does my code successfully pass these two arrays to the function?" Yup.

Comment: If it's not working, move the function above the rest of the code.

Comment: How is it failing? What errors do you get?

Comment: Do you know how to debug? console.log() is your friend.

Comment: Thank you all! really helpful for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. it works.. You should use `var` or `let` to initialize your variables.

```
function sortWords(arr1, arr2) {
   alert(arr1.length + arr2.length); // gives 8 it works!
}

var wordList = ["apple", "have", "pear", "here"];
var wordCount = [3, 1, 3, 5];
sortWords(wordList, wordCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the following:

```
wordList.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
}
```

This will sort your word list from the longest word to the shortest in one easy step.

Answer (score 0):

You **are** passing the arrays to the function correctly. Want to test it?

```
var wordList = ["apple", "have", "pear", "here"],
    wordCount = [3, 1, 3, 5];

sortWords(wordList, wordCount);

function sortWords(arr1, arr2) {
  for(fruits in arr1){
      console.log(arr1[fruits]);
  }
  for(numbers in arr2){
    console.log(arr2[numbers]);
  }
}
```

**Note**:

1. Always initialize your variables before using them, in order to avoid any issues regarding **[scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)**.
2. Look at your browser's console in order to **see** the output of the above test.

Any questions? feel free to ask in the comments below.